# SQL query to Eloquent conversion

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

How do I transform below SQL statement to Eloquent?

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE (`to`=$myID AND `from`=$guestID) OR (`to`=$guestID AND `from`=$myID)
```

Comment: Use nested queries. I'd suggest starting with the documentation [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) and [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `where` and `orWhere` closures for [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping):

```
Message::where(function($q) use($myId, $guestId) {
    $q->where('to', $myId)->where('from', $guestId);
})
->orWhere(function($q) use($myId, $guestId) {
    $q->where('to', $guestId)->where('from', $myId);
})
->get();
```